# Scrolldown a table inside a div tag in through Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping

I wanted to scroll till the last row of https://covid19.who.int/table using Selenium framework in python.

See below my snippet

```
url = 'https://covid19.who.int/table/'
Path_ChromeDriver = 'E:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Path_ChromeDriver)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
target = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@role="rowgroup"]//div[@role="row"][last()]//div[@class="column_Deaths td"]/div')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", target)
```

But this doesn't help me to scroll down the div tag. Any help will be highly appreciated. I am looking to extract all the data from the table starting from the “Americas” row.

See screenshot for data I need.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R70IC.png)
Thanks in advance

Comment: I want to scroll down till the end of table

Answer (score 1):

first, you can use css selector to select the table you want, like the below code, why added a div behind because target is the div under the div which class is tbody

```
$('div[class="tbody"]>div')
```

second, using scrollTop to scroll the table, give the number that can control how much you want to scroll

```
$('div[class="tbody"]>div').scrollTop=10000
```

if you put this code in console, the table will scroll down~

Final, change a little bit to fit in the script

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('div[class=\"tbody\"]>div').scrollTop=10000")
```

here you go~

Answer (score 0):

First get all the rows of the table using this line of code.

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class=\"tr depth_0 \"]")
```

Now scroll to last row like this:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()",rows[len(rows)-1]
```

By this, the table will be scrolled till the last row which will be in rows variable.

So, if you want to scroll to the end of the table, you will have to use a while loop and get all rows again and scrollIntoView the last row. While loop because I checked that finding all rows will only return 20-28 rows which are visible on the page. So, use a while loop to go till the end.